# Дизайнер окон WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

После создания WPF-приложения не отображается дизайнер окон, есть только файл с разметкой xaml. Как открыть дизайнер?

**UPD:** при нажатии "Открыть в конструкторе" открывается код, но не дизайнер.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нажимаем правой кнопкой по файлу и выбираем в контекстном меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Включить дизайнер можно тут

[image: Включить дизайнер можно тут]

Comment: не получается. вставил скриншоты в текст вопроса

Comment: @mtrfnv обновил ответ